# Radio Button Sets Value in Spinner Calculation

Tags: android

I'm completely new to programming - and I'm stuck on what is probably a very basic function. I've tried other resources (including text material) but cannot find anything which matches my example. I'm totally lost on this and my code will probably reflect this as well.

I am trying to calculate a value which uses both a radio button (with two options) and a spinner (with seven options). The radio button selects a speed which effects the calculations made on the spinner values.

In order to properly calculate my sum, I need the calculate button to recognise which radio button is selected and then input a value accordingly (however, the value is not what is on the buttons e.g. rb1 = "5.5" but has a corresponding value of 45; rb2 = "7" but has a corresponding value of 55).

The calculate button then needs to input either value into a formula along with the value from the spinner.

Comment: Post the relevant code of yours.

Comment: @Aleksander Apologies I can't seem to get it edited correctly...using the back tick doesn't retain my formatting?

Comment: Use 4 spaces in the beginning of each line to post entire blocks of code. As for the back tick, or whatever it's called ;) I don't know bout formatting. It'll format everything as code and that should do. Any extra bits in there will only make it difficult for people to copy-paste your code. And you don't want that because then they are less likely to figure out your problem.